How to provide entitlements to an external v2ray binary for macos app in xcode?
App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "production.myapp.pkg/Payload/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/v2ray" )] Refer to App Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox for more information on sandboxing your app.
The way I'm made it is that I have v2ray binary embedded as a resource in my main app. I have created and included the entitlements file, but it seems to be ignored as well.
I tried making the file myself, the app that requires it is signed/has the right entitlements and I tried looking up tutorials, but ended up even more confused than when I started.
